# Add price range search in Business Catalyst

Tags: business-catalyst

Could you tell me how to add a price range in Business Catalyst?

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to set up a Product Search? If so, here are the instructions at BC Knowledgebase: http://kb.worldsecuresystems.com/652/bc_652.html

Just select a price range using dropdown menu: http://prntscr.com/105oei

Does this help?

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
$("#search-826").children('div').each(function() {
            if ($(this).data("listing-price") <= 20.00) {
                $(this).hide();
            }
        });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="search-results" id="search-826">
<div class="product" data-listing-price="2.00">
  <div class="image">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150">
  </div>

            <h3>Parasol</h3>
        <h4>£2.00</h4>
</div>
<div class="product" data-listing-price="5.00">
  <div class="image">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150">
  </div>

            <h3>Parasol</h3>
        <h4>£5.00</h4>
</div>
<div class="product" data-listing-price="25.00">
  <div class="image">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150">
  </div>

            <h3>Parasol</h3>
        <h4>£25.00</h4>
</div>
<div class="product" data-listing-price="250.00">
  <div class="image">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150">
  </div>

            <h3>Parasol</h3>
        <h4>£250.00</h4>
</div>
<div class="product" data-listing-price="50.00">
  <div class="image">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150">
  </div>

            <h3>Parasol</h3>
        <h4>£50.00</h4>
</div></div>
```